# How to determine which scene is the new one upon duplication?

Tags: python

Let's say the user has multiple scenes, and some of them may be named *Scene.001*, etc.

If I do `bpy.ops.scene.new(type='FULL_COPY')`, how do I know which one is the new one?

Normally I'd expect the new scene to update the context and this to work:

```
bpy.ops.scene.new(type='FULL_COPY')
copy = bpy.context.scene
```

It does work if you type it into the console. However, that doesn't appear to be the case if I put this into an addon script (`bpy.context.scene` seems to update only after the operator is done, which is not useful).

Any ideas how I can determine which scene is the new one? Is this a bug?

Comment: `context.scene.name` is up-to-date if I print it immediately after the call to `scene.new()`, please post your code.